# How manage errors on the same fields and forms

Tags: laravel

This is my code, double form so this is the same input name like eg. email. When i send form with empty email field i have an error how can i display one error to one correct form. Now of course i see this error on each form.

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" class="col-md-9" id="webinar-form-{{ $data->id }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Adres email">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    @error('email')
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        </div>
    @enderror
</form>

<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" class="col-md-9" id="webinar-form-{{ $data->id }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Adres email">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    @error('email')
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        </div>
    @enderror
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your email, probably something like this

```
<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" class="col-md-9" id="webinar-form-{{ $data->id }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control @error('email_1') is-invalid @enderror" name="email_1" value="{{ old('email_1') }}" placeholder="Adres email">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    @error('email_1')
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        </div>
    @enderror
</form>

<form action="{{ route('signup') }}" method="post" class="col-md-9" id="webinar-form-{{ $data->id }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control @error('email_2') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email_2') }}" placeholder="Adres email">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    @error('email_2')
        <div class="alert alert-light" role="alert">
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        </div>
    @enderror
</form>
```

Because your input name is same for both form. And you can set the variable in your controller to match the name

Comment: this is dynamic, if i do like this `email_1` and `email_2` how can i add his to validate in controller?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [array validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-arrays) in laravel

```
$request->validate([
        "email"    => "required|array",
        "email.*"  => "required|email|unique:table_name",
    ]);
```

Use this code in controller and check it's working or not.